# Як правильно вживати та писати “Запорозька Січ" або "Запорізька Січ”?

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, фонетика

Блукаючи просторами Інетрнет ресурсів, натрапив на [місцеву сторінку](http://hortica.zp.ua/ua/guide/north/89-sich) Національного заповідника "Хортиця" - "*Запорозька Січ*". Як же так, особисто я здавна вважав що "Січ" - саме "Запорізька"?

Вікіпедія [вживає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%96%D1%87) ці два написи як синоніми:

> **Запоро́зька Сі́ч або Запорі́зька Сі́ч** — укріплений осередок нереєстрового Війська Запорозького Низового другої половини XVI — кінця XVIII століття, що був розташований за порогами Дніпра. Збереглися відомості про сім Запорозьких Січей, що наслідували одна одну.
> У сучасності термін Запорозька Січ також іноді вживається для позначення усієї території та устрою Війська Запорозького.

[Існує](http://sich.zp.ua/) навіть однойменне видання місцевої влади: "*Запорозька Січ*".
Вікі "Українопедія" теж [вживає](http://ukrainopedia.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%96%D1%87) написання "Запорозька Січ"

> Запорізька Січ — військово-суспільний і духовний центр українського козацтва раннього нового часу. Головний осередок нереєстрового Війська Запорозького середини 16 — середині 17 століття. Політично-адміністративний центр держави Війська Запорозького Низового з другої половини 17 — кінця 18 століття. Розташовувалася за дніпровими порогами, в середній течії Дніпра. Протягом раннього нового часу існувало вісім Запорозьких Січей.

Та й взагалі, написання "Запорозька Січ" є досить [поширеним](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%96%D1%87&client=aff-maxthon-maxthon4&hs=Syu&affdom=maxthon.com&channel=t26&ei=s7LjWsTiLcKwsQH_6ouABA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1204&bih=875).

СУМ-20 теж [наводить](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=217163&page=1029) дані слова як синоніми:

> **ЗАПОРО́ЗЬКИЙ, ЗАПОРІ́ЗЬКИЙ**, а, е. 1. іст. **Стос. до запорожців, Запорожжя.** А тим часом Запорозьку зброю Виніс батько із комори, Розгляда, радіє, Приміряє... ніби знову Старий молодіє! (Т. Шевченко); [Кобзар:] Ой, обізветься пан Підкова, Отаман-батько запорозький: Гей, друзі молодці, Браття козаки-запорожці! (І. Нечуй-Левицький); На червонощокій і білобородій голові розвівалася сива запорізька чуприна (І. Багряний); Мов живих, уявляла Єлька тих лицарів запорозьких, бачила їхні дозори на степових могилах, зблиски шабель, коли вони б'ються в куряві (О. Гончар); Головне, що зробив останній запорозький кошовий, – зберіг цвіт козацтва (Д. Білий).
> 2. **тільки запорі́зький.** Стос. до запоріжців і міста Запоріжжя. Був травень, розцвітав без, по запорізьких гаях лящали солов'ї (У. Самчук); – У нас же зараз на гастролях .. і Львівський імені Заньковецької, і Запорізький імені Щорса [театри] (В. Нестайко); В Україні є поклади сірки (у Львівській, Івано-Франківській і Тернопільській областях) і графіту (у Кіровоградській і Запорізькій областях) (з навч. літ.).

А от мовознавець, доктор філологічних наук - *Олександр Пономарів*, професор Інституту журналістики Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка в своїй книзі "Культура слова: мовностилістичні поради" досить докладно [розбирає](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/fonetyka) та пояснює даний випадок написання:

> Багатьох цікавить питання, як правильно писати — *Запорозька Січ* чи *Запорізька Січ*. В останні роки на сторінках преси, в художній літературі почали розмежовувати два поняття, позначаючи це розмежування на письмі: запорозький уживають тоді, коли йдеться про добу Козаччини, а запорізький застосовують у назвах, пов'язаних із нашою сучасністю. Таке розрізнення видається штучним. Мовознавці давно навели достатню кількість доказів на користь форми з `і`. Основний аргумент тих, хто обстоює варіант Запорозька Січ, полягає в тому, що «Січ була за порогами». Цілком правильно. Але ж в однині буде *поріг*, наприклад Кодацький. Візьмемо інші випадки. Слово роздоріжжя походить від дорога. У закритому складі пишемо й вимовляємо `і`, у відкритому `о`. У топонімі *Тернопіль* друга частина пов'язана зі словом поле, то що ж — будемо писати *Тернополь*? Вийде, нібито наша мова розвивається в зворотному напрямку.
>
> Звук `і` в українській мові вельми поширений. Уживаємо його на місці звука, що позначався колись літерою «ять»: *віра, дід, ліс* (пор. рос. *вера, дед, лес*, п. *wiara, dziad, las*); у закритих складах на місці `о`, `е`: *сніп — снопа, поріг — порога, дороги — доріг, піч — печі, Київ — Києва*. Перехід `о`, `е` в `і` розпочався в X столітті і завершився в XIII столітті. Цей процес відбувався рівнобіжно з занепадом зредукованих голосних `ъ` й `ь`. Тож на час заснування Січі за порогами ікання вже стало нормою живого мовлення. Але на письмі ще довго діяли норми староукраїнської мови, де такі фонетичні зміни не позначалися. Не відбивали всіх фонетичних змін і літописи, де бачимо написання *Кыєвъ, Києвъ, Кієвъ, Львовъ, Черниговъ*. Але ж звемо їх тепер *Київ, Львів, Чернігів*.
>
> У XIX столітті застосовували традиційний правопис, за яким писали *стôлъ, пѣсня*, а вимовляли *стіл, пісня*. Наприклад, «Гомôнъ, гомôнъ по дубровѣ» (Українські пісні видані М. Максимовичем. К., 1962. Фотокопія з видання 1827 р., с. 6). Пантелеймон Куліш запровадив фонетичний правопис, яким ми користуємося й тепер (однак той правопис довго пробивав собі шлях, поки не запанував на всій етнографічній території України). Форма Запорозька Січ підтримувалася не лише тим, що більшість історичних праць українські вчені мусили писати, на жаль, іншими мовами, а й тенденцією наближати вимову й написання до російської мови. Отож і сталося так, що в нас козацький полковник Максим Кривоніс, а ініціатор стахановських методів на залізничному транспорті Петро Кривонос, Людмила Старицька-Черняхівська, а радянський генерал Іван Черняховський, хоч усі вони —діти української землі.
>
> Тритомний «Російсько-український словник», що вийшов 1968 року, готувався за часів хрущовської відлиги, звідти повикидали багато нав’язаних раніше росіянізмів. Тому там є лише одна нормативна форма Запорізька Січ (т. 3, с. 270). Так само в УРЕ, яку редагував видатний український поет Микола Бажан (т. 5, с. 181—186). **Отож як свою прадавню столицю ми звемо Київ у всіх випадках, так само й Козацьку Республіку маємо називати Запорізька Січ — відповідно до законів нашої милозвучної мови.**

Отже, спираючись на роз'яснення авторитетного фахівця, таки пишемо та вживаємо саме вислів "Запорі́зька Сі́ч", а не "Запоро́зька Сі́ч"?

Comment: На моє переконання, ви вже провели повний цикл дослідження теми. Є розлоге пояснення професора філології, яке ґрунтується як на історичних, так і на нормативних джерелах і доходить висновку, що пишемо якимось чином. І є безіменні сайти, яки пишуть іншим чином і нічого не пояснюють. На мою думку, вибір є очевидним. P.S. Коли робите пошук по фразі, ставте шукане словосполучення у лапки, бо інакше Ґуґл самостійно включає синоніми.

Comment: А чому варіант "Запорожська січь" навіть не розглядається? Я багато разів зустрічав його. Чи це русізм?

Comment: @AlexSodin мабуть-таки "росіянізм".

Answer (score 4):

[Один добродій у Фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pusatupravylnoucrainskoyu/permalink/882578341947317/?comment_id=896529873885497) детально розібрав цей випадок:

> З погляду йсторичної фонології... в першу чергу правильні суть як раз форми <Запорожжя, запорозький>, а також у непрямих відмінках <запорожц-> – попри слушно завважений закритий склад.
>
> Чому?
>
> З одного боку є правда же давнє *о в прапівденнозахідноруських говірках, що лягли в основу руської-вкраїнської мови в складах закритих (з історичного погляду правильніше казати: перед складами з »німим« або »слабким« єром) було звужено, піднято й просунено вперед (в сучасному чинному письмі літературного стандарту літера <і>). З другого ж боку, в одному випадку умова ся була обмежена, а саме в сполуках, що походять від прасловянських *olT, *orT (*T є умовне позначення будь-якого приголосного), які в мові давньоруській дали, відповідно, <-оло-, -оро->. До таких слів належать, наприклад: <молоко, горобець, голова, морок> тощо; їх (пізні) прасловянські форми (спрощено) мали вигляд: *molko (←*melk-), *orb-, *golva-, *gord-. Голосний /о/ в другому складі в них є походження вторинного – явище се є звано »повноголос«. Ю. Шевелів у своїм труді Історична фонологія вкраїнської мови, питання се розглянувши, пояснив же таке /о/ було фонетично »ширше« за /о/ первинне, що й пинило його звуження, підвищення та просунення вперед. Саме це пояснює, чому в українській є <морок>, а не +<морік>, <город>, а не +<горід>, <горох>, а не +<горіх> (плід стручковий, не плутати з »горіхом«), <молочний, молочко>, а не +<молічний, молічко> тощо, хоча в усіх сих формах є /о/ друге в складі критому. Друге /о/ в таких складах, з точки зору йсторичної фонології може бути характеризовано як »вставне«.
>
> В українській мові, втім, є й багато випадків, коли в словах, що походять від давніх прасловянських сполук *olT, *orT, замість очікуваного за вищеподаним викладом <-оло-, -оро-> маємо таки »звуження« другого /о/ в <-олі-, -орі->: <голів, поріг, ворін, воріт>. Спричинив се їнший історичний фонологічний чинник, а саме: в добі прасловянській єри в кінці слів, що згодом стали »слабкі, німі« й відпали, могли бути наголошені, зокрема се стосується родового відмінка множини ймен жіночого роду з наголосом на <-а> в закінченні називного відмінка. Тобто, наприклад, слово <голова> в родовому множини в давньоруській мові мало форму <головъ>; з такого написання наголосу на /ъ/ невидно, та факти, засновані на порівнянні зі спорідненими мовами балтськими, та їншими словянськими, та й розвиток фонології самої вкраїнської мови прозраджують наголос тут на кінцевому /ъ/. З утратою кінцевого /ъ/ зникла й можливість самого наголосу на тому місці, а втрату сю в українській мові було компенсовано додатковим »звуженням« того »вторинного, вставного« */о/, тобто: */головъ́/ → <голі́в>. Те саме є й з формами <ворін> (род.мн. від »ворона«), <воріт> (род.мн. від »ворота«) тощо. Те саме могло відбутися й у разі форми <поріг>, яка походить від прасловянського * porg-, з якого мала би постати форма /порог/, коли й тут був древній наголос на кінцевому /ъ/ (*/порогъ́). Слід завважити же одна з прикмет давнього наголошеного »слабкого, німого« єра в кінці слова може бути наголос на закінченні в сучасній українській мові, тож форма /порогів/ цілком може свідчити про наголос на кінцевому /ъ/ в давній формі */порогъ/). Коли так, то форма <поріг> у сучасній українській літературній мові є правильна з погляду йсторичної фонології. Та чи була така сама умова, тобто наголос на »німому, слабкому« єрі в формах похідних від <поріг>? Праформи сучасних <Запорожжя~Запоріжжя>, <запорозький~запорізький>, <запорожц-> були, відповідно: <запорожьє>, <запорожьскъи>, <запорожьц->. Сталий наголос на /-ро-~-рі-/ в сих формах свідчить радше про відсутність наголосу на */ь/ в складі /-жь-/ в найдавніші часи, а тому й про відсутність передумови для форм <Запоріжжя, запорізький, запоріжц->.
>
> Втім, покладаючи, на підставі вищенаведеного викладу, форми з <о> за первинно правильні, форми з <і> не можемо класти за неправильні, виникли бо вони, хоча й вторинно (інерційно-аналогійно) на тлі суто вкраїнському.
>
> Таким чином, у першу чергу слід класти за правильні, питомі вкраїнські, що цілком відповідають розвитку фонології вкраїнської мови, тут форми з <о>, а в другу чергу, хоча й як вторинні, але виниклі на тлі вкраїнському, форми з <і>. **Тобто, правильні суть обидві форми, з першістю форм з /о/**.